# Kendo-ui Angular 7 How to export multiple grids as one excel file?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have seen this question asked a few times before for Angular 2 however I don't see a question specifically asking about Angular 6 or 7.

I have a page of multiple grids that I'm trying to export as one excel file. Even if it's multiple worksheets.

```
<!-- Section header 1 -->
<kendo-grid [data]="data.something" scrollable="none">
  <kendo-grid-column field="item"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="amount"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="price"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>

<!-- Section header 2 -->
<kendo-grid [data]="data.something2" scrollable="none">
  <kendo-grid-column field="item"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="amount"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="price"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

These are inside a few wrapper components with the top level wrapper being a kendo-pdf-export tag.

How would I go about exporting the grids into one Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the approach for exporting multiple data sets to separate Excel sheets, outlined in the following documentation article:

[Excel Export demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/excelexport/how-to/export-to-separate-sheets/)

... or the one for exporting Master-Detail Grids (after adjusting it to your needs):

[Master-detail Grid excel export demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/#toc-exporting-master-detail-grids)

Scenario is not the same, but the approach still boils down to obtaining the data for all involved Grids, and outputting it in the Excel document.

None of the outlined approaches is Angular 6/7-specific, and all approaches that are working with Angular 2, 4 or 5 should be applicable in Angular 6 and 7 too.